# sudo: systemctl: command not found

Tags: systemd

I have a Raspberry Pi 2 B+ running Btsync server, which I installed a couple of years ago. I wanted to upgrade this to Resilio Sync following their instructions on [this page](https://help.getsync.com/hc/en-us/articles/206178924). All's good up up until the command

```
sudo systemctl enable resilio-sync
```

Which throws the error

```
sudo: systemctl: command not found
```

I've installed all updates for the OS, Raspbian, and attempted

```
apt-get install systemd
```

Which results in

```
Package systemd is not available, but is referred to by another package

[...]

E: Package 'systemd' has no installation candidate
```

I'm lost here, I don't even know what I'm doing. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you using jessie or wheezy?  `cat /etc/os-release`. Edit the information into your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you must be using Debian Wheezy, which is not based on `systemd`. If possible, upgrading the OS to Debian Jessie is recommended, which is based on systemd.

Answer (score 2):

On pre-systemd Debian/Raspian systems you should be able use these commands:

automatically start the service during boot:

```
update-rc.d resilio-sync defaults
```

manually start the service:

```
service start resilio-sync
```

manually stop the service:

```
service stop resilio-sync
```

For more details look at this [cheat sheet](https://www.jamescoyle.net/cheat-sheets/791-update-rc-d-cheat-sheet) or just [duckduckgo for update-rc.d](https://duckduckgo.com/html?q=update%2Drc.d).

Most Linux system have switched to systemd. So, if you want to known how starting services works, better update and look at systemd. There is a [blog series](https://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/#thesystemdforadministratorsblogseries) that explains systemd pretty well, I recommend you have a look at it.

Comment: Thanks, P Gerber. Could you expand on this a bit (I'm a noob); what is this actually doing? How would I then start/stop the service?

Comment: updated the answer